# How to write an AngularJS directive that formats the model value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a directive to have `<input>` elements accepting floats using `,` instead of `.` as the separator.

I took [the example from the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) that parses the user input to accept both `.` and `,` as separators by adding a new parser to `controller.$parsers`.

However, I now want `10.5` to be displayed as `10,5` (which is not the case currently if I set the value in my model using JS).

**So where in a directive can I add a "formatter" function?** (like I can add a "parser" function)

Here is the directive:

```
app.directive('inputFloat', function () {
    var FLOAT_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/;
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            controller.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                if (FLOAT_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                    controller.$setValidity('float', true);
                    if (typeof viewValue === "number") {
                        return viewValue;
                    } else {
                        return parseFloat(viewValue.replace(',', '.'));
                    }
                } else {
                    controller.$setValidity('float', false);
                    return undefined;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is how it is used in the template:

```
<input input-float type="text" ng-model="input.value.digitalValue">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `controller.$formatters`.

see [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#properties_%24formatters) for more info.

Comment: Wonderful thank you, that's exactly that :) I should have probably found it myself given the name is simply "formatters" but I have to admit the docs are really a pain to browse, I'm always lost :/